# Please revise my code, in which Out of range issue appears

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a form and fill it up with data from another xlsx. However when I loop through string array by Do While method, it gives out of range Error.

Checked "i" increment variable start, however it is not limited from beyond. Somehow it may get out of range.

```
Dim innerReviewers() As String: Dim split_ETO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_KGO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_PGO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_NUO_reviewers() As String
    Dim split_AMO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_VSKO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_VIO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_ABO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_ITO_reviewers() As String
    Dim split_UIG_reviewers() As String: Dim split_ENBO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_LETO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_Non_ERBE_reviewers() As String: Dim split_ERBE_reviewers() As String
    innerReviewers() = Split(reviewers(n), ",")
    split_ETO_reviewers() = Split(ETO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_KGO_reviewers() = Split(KGO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_PGO_reviewers() = Split(PGO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_NUO_reviewers() = Split(NUO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_AMO_reviewers() = Split(AMO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_VSKO_reviewers() = Split(VSKO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_VIO_reviewers() = Split(VIO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_ABO_reviewers() = Split(ABO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_ITO_reviewers() = Split(ITO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_UIG_reviewers() = Split(UIG_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_ENBO_reviewers() = Split(ENBO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_LETO_reviewers() = Split(LETO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_Non_ERBE_reviewers() = Split(Non_ERBE_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_ERBE_reviewers() = Split(ERBE_reviewers(n), ",")
    reviewersCount = 0
    If Len(Join(innerReviewers)) > 0 & Len(Join(split_ETO_reviewers)) > 0 & Len(Join(split_KGO_reviewers)) > 0 & Len(Join(split_PGO_reviewers)) > 0 & Len(Join(split_NUO_reviewers)) > 0 & Len(Join(split_AMO_reviewers)) > 0 & Len(Join(split_VSKO_reviewers)) > 0 & Len(Join(split_VIO_reviewers)) > 0 & Len(Join(split_ABO_reviewers)) > 0 & Len(Join(split_ITO_reviewers)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The current document (" & docCode(n) & ") has not been reviewed by colleques! (Archiving function of list of non-reviewed docs is not ready.)", vbOKOnly, "Warning for lacking reviewers!"
        Dim non_reviewed_docs As Object
        Dim archive As String
        archive = "C:\Users\C3642\Desktop\FU5504-NY-01\Non_reviewed_documents_list.xlsx"
        Set non_reviewed_docs = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(archive, True)
        With non_reviewed_docs.Worksheet(1)
            .Cells(n + 1, 1).Value = docCode(n)
        End With
        non_reviewed_docs.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If
    With outXl.Worksheets(1)
        reviewersCount = UBound(innerReviewers) - LBound(innerReviewers) + 1
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
        Do While (i < reviewersCount & i < 12)
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = innerReviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_ETO_reviewers) - LBound(split_ETO_reviewers) + 1
            Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = ETO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_KGO_reviewers) - LBound(split_KGO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = KGO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_PGO_reviewers) - LBound(split_PGO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = PGO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_NUO_reviewers) - LBound(split_NUO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = NUO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_AMO_reviewers) - LBound(split_AMO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = AMO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_VSKO_reviewers) - LBound(split_VSKO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = VSKO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_VIO_reviewers) - LBound(split_VIO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = VIO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_ABO_reviewers) - LBound(split_ABO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = ABO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_ITO_reviewers) - LBound(split_ITO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = ITO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_UIG_reviewers) - LBound(split_UIG_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = UIG_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_ENBO_reviewers) - LBound(split_ENBO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = ENBO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_LETO_reviewers) - LBound(split_LETO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = LETO_reviewers(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        'reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_Non_ERBE_reviewers) - LBound(split_Non_ERBE_reviewers) + 1
        'Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
        '   .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = Non_ERBE_reviewers(i)
        '     i = i + 1
        'Loop
        'reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_ERBE_reviewers) - LBound(split_ERBE_reviewers) + 1
        'Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
        '   .Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = ERBE_reviewers(i)
        '     i = i + 1
        'Loop
    End With
    Dim concatenatedfileName As String
    concatenatedfileName = docResponsible(n) & "_" & docCode(n) & ".xlsx"
    outXl.SaveAs Filename:=concatenatedfileName, FileFormat:=51
    outXl.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

I expect i variable in routine ".Cells(16 + i, 4).Value = innerReviewers(i + 1)" remainnig below 12, but for the first loop, when it reaches i=7, gives the error.

Comment: `i < reviewersCount & i < 12` should be `i < reviewersCount And i < 12`  in vba `&` and `And` are not the same thing.

Comment: You never reset the value of `i`

Comment: Surely there's an easier way to set this up... Also, what is `n`?